# How to escape special characters in xpath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I am searching for an HTML node that contains this text:

```
(~! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + { } | : " < > ? ` - = [ ] \ ; ‘ , . / ).
```

But xpath is obviously having problems because it's not recognizing the above as an actual text to search for but rather as part of the xpath expression, which is why I am getting the error:

```
is not a valid XPath expression.
```

So how would I convert the above to a text or string to avoid this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Considering contains() only accepts a string as the search parameter anyway, I don't see how this is an issue.

Comment: I'll give that a try, I am new to xpath and have never heard of contains() before. Can you give an example of how to use it?

Comment: Can you provide XML (or) HTML tree to evaluate XPath.